# Xpath in XML not working because of xml namespace field

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, hl7-v3

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bookstore xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 PORT_MT020001.xsd" type="Observation" classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
    <book>
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

When I try to use `XMLDocument.SelectNodes()` on the above xml like this:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//book");
Console.WriteLine(xmlNodelist.Count);
```

I get a result of:

```
0
```

When I change the `xmlns` attribute value in root node to empty like this:

```
<bookstore xmlns="" ...........>
```

then I get back the proper result of:

```
2
```

Why is this happening? The `xmlns` attribute value in root node is vital to me. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered 1755 times (search for "XPath Default Namespace"). I chose one of these questions arbitrarily as a duplicate, because it has the most upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why your `Count` shows 0 for books is because books comes under a specific namespace. If it was outside the tags that had a namespace, then your query would have resulted in 2.

To make your queries work for tags that are part of a namespace (parent tags with namespace means all children inherits that namespace), you can use the code like this,

```
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

    XmlNodeList xmlNodelist = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//x:book", nsmgr);
    Console.WriteLine(xmlNodelist.Count); // Prints 2
```

What this does is creates a `NamespaceManager` with default namespaceUri of the document and uses `x` (or you can use any letter / word) to associate the tags with in searches. When you search for nodes, use this letter and the namespacemanager to get the results you need.

Comment: superb!!! it worked! thanks alot